# Python tkinter update function freezes main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a windows application with a python API (supports python 3). You can provide a class that has a main function. On program startup, an instance of this class is created, and the main function is called periodically. I can configure the frequency, but nothing else. (I cannot change the way the API works)

Now, I'd like to use tkinter for some visualizations, charts, and so on. Here is an example of my current class structure:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Script:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.count = 0
    
    def main(self):
        # do some stuff
        print(str(self.count))
        self.count += 1
        
        # update gui
        self.root.update()

# This is to simulate the software behavior.

import time

scriptInstance = Script()

for i in range(0, 20 * 10):
    scriptInstance.main()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The main issue I have is, that the root.update() method freezes the main-function as long as you interact with Tkinter. You can see that with the example above, that the number is not counting up as long as you are moving the window. Is there a way to prevent that?

I tried to call the root.update() form another thread, which did not work because Tkinter does not allow that.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Tried `after()` method?

Comment: Yes, I tired `self.root.after(1, self.root.update)` instead of calling `self.root.update()` directly. but it does not work. Gui update did not take place and the window did not appear. In other examples `after()` is always used to run the other code, and tkinter mainloop or update is called afterwards. This does not work in my case since the API expects the main function to return.

Comment: Ive made some changes and added an answer, take a look

Comment: Please note that after(1, func) waits only one microsecond. Did you mean after(1000, func) ?

Comment: I do not need a delay (and increasing the number did not change the result). The idea was to continue the `main()`-method and let the `self.root.update()` be triggered by `after()`. However, I guess you need to call `update()` to handle the `after()` mehod. ( chicken egg dilemma)